# What is the exact purpose of Annotations in AngularJS 2.0

Tags: angular, annotations

I have been learning AngularJs 2.0 for sometime.

I'm really confused with a newly introduced concept, **Annotations**.

Can anyone clarifying me what is the purpose of annotations?

Comment: Google is good at answering questions like this: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/03/the-difference-between-annotations-and-decorators.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotations in AngularJS are used to avoid getting your code broken after running a tool like Grunt or Gulp to minify and uglify it.

For example if you have:

```
myModule.controller('myController', function($scope){
    $scope.cars = ['toyota', 'honda'];
});
```

After running a build tool your code will break because the `$scope` parameter in the anonymous function will be uglyfied to let's say `a` or `b` which then breaks the reference to `$scope.cars`.

to fix this problem you have to `annotate` your code...

```
myModule.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.cars = ['toyota', 'honda'];
}]);
```

...which will then leave the `$scope` parameter untouched and won't break your program.

There are solutions to this. There's an NPM package called [`ngAnnotate`](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) which will annotate your Angular code for you.